# PHP_EOL not changing on a new line

Tags: php

I'm using `PHP_EOL` but is not writing on a new line

```
 echo $clock." ".$system->__toString().PHP_EOL;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Is this output to a browser?  If so you need to use HTML - `<br />`

Comment: Use comma instead of dot with echo(). No need to concat.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is the real output?